# Getting error while trying to access static model function in codeigniter model using HMVC (Note* search a lot but not find any exact answer)

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am working with codeigniter HMVC, I created a module admin. follow the below structure:-

application/modules/admin/controllers/Login.php
application/modules/admin/models/login.php

Model code:
[image]
Controller code:
[image]
I created a static function in my modules model (login.php) is getGmInfo().
when I try to access this function using Login::getGmInfo(). its showing me error:
[image]

Comment: can i see your controller ??

Comment: I haven't worked with codeigniter but this seems short on information. What is the error?

Comment: Please check the question details I post there with attachments.

Comment: you may not be loading model there 

try 
this->load->model('your_model')

Comment: Yes I already loaded my model like  $this->load->model('admin/login');

Comment: @Santosh check attached screen, I already loaded model. and error attachments

Comment: check my answer below .. :)

Comment: *Please before answer question, Please check attached screen whats all I did and why I am getting error.

Answer (score 1):

You can load any library in a static context by loading the globally accessible **CodeIgniter** instance with get_instance, resulting in:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->model('your_model');
```

Comment: That would be nice if you add some description to your answer

Comment: could you write full syntax how it call please .. your answer not understandable .

Comment: hope this will make sense